# MongoDB allowDiskUse not working..

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

Experts.

I'm new to MongoDB, but know enough to get my self in trouble.. case in point:

```
db.test.aggregate(
[
    {$group: {_id: {email: "$email", gender: "$gender"}, cnt: {$sum: 1}}}, 
    {$group: {_id: "$_id.email", cnt: {$sum: 1}}}, 
    {$match: {cnt: 2}}
], 
    {allowDiskUse : true}
)
```

and no matter what variations I try, I keep getting the same error ("Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in"):

> Error("Printing Stack Trace")@:0 ()@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37
>   ([object Array],[object Object])@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:866
>   @(shell):7
>
> uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {   "errmsg" : "exception:
>   Received error in response from mongo1.mscnet.com:27017: { $err:
>   \"Exceeded memory limit for $group, **but didn't allow external sort.
>   Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.**\", code: 16945 }",    "code" : 16945,
>     "ok" : 0
>       }

FYI: I'm using Mongo 2.6

Comment: Are you definitely using a 2.6 shell? What does `version()` return in the `mongo` shell? Also, are you using any shell extensions such as Mongo-Hacker? If so, I would try starting the shell using `mongo --norc` to test without extensions. Your syntax looks correct so I'm suspecting you may inadvertently be using a version of the `aggregate()` helper that does not support passing options to the aggregation command (which were added in the MongoDB 2.6 shell).

Comment: I'm using "MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5".  Although, I was using a third-party app called RoboMongo (Version 0.8.4).  I'm now using the CMD shell with --norc .. and that seems to work.. I guess it was my client.  

But can you explain something for me?.. The aggregation doesn't happen on my PC (does it?).  I don't see any network / cpu usage on my pc.  So what is the "client", and how/why does it effect the processing of data?

Thank you!

Comment: Clients like the `mongo` shell or Robomongo provide [`aggregate()` helpers](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to make it more convenient to work with the underlying [`aggregate` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/aggregate/) that runs on your MongoDB server. In versions of MongoDB prior to 2.6 the aggregate command did not support any options so older versions of the `aggregate()` helpers will ignore those. If `--norc` works for the `mongo` shell I suspect you have an older version of Mongo-Hacker (I committed a fix in August 2014)

Comment: I see.  So the client sends additional code (helpers) to the server that the server uses to build the execution-path and result - not just the actual command. 

Thank you again!

Comment: `mongo` shell helpers just manipulate parameters before sending the command to the server (for example, allowing you to pass an aggregation pipeline as either an array or a list of pipeline steps). FYI, you can see the helper code in the `mongo` shell by invoking without the (), eg: `db.test.aggregate`

Comment: Robomongo has not upgraded to the 2.6 shell and might not for some time. That's the issue.

Answer (score 22):

Please use aggregate query in run command,it will allow to use allowDiskUse tag.

```
db.runCommand(
   { aggregate: "test",
     pipeline: [
                {$group: {_id: {email: "$email", gender: "$gender"}, cnt: {$sum: 1}}}, 
                {$group: {_id: "$_id.email", cnt: {$sum: 1}}}, 
                {$match: {cnt: 2}}
               ],
     allowDiskUse: true
   }
)
```

Answer (score 18):

If you are working with *m10 or later* version of MongoDB Atlas, below is the fix for `{allowDiskUse: true};`
If you are accessing data from application via mongoose then, it should be syntax as function. For example:

MongoDb Query:

```
db.collection.user.aggregate([], {allowDiskUse: true})
```

With Mongoose:

```
User.aggregate([]).allowDiskUse(true);
```

This will resolve error from application :)

Answer (score 16):

Try writing like this,

```
db.stocks.aggregate([
                     { $project : { cusip: 1, date: 1, price: 1, _id: 0 } },
                     { $sort : { cusip : 1, date: 1 } }
                    ],
                     {
                       allowDiskUse: true
                     }
                    );
```

And One more thing,
Your error about maximum document size is inherent to Mongo. Mongo can never return a document (or array thereof) larger than 16 megabytes. I can't tell you why because you didn't mention anything about data size, but it probably means that the document you're building as an end result is too large. Try decreasing the $limit parameter, maybe? Start by setting it to 1, run a test, then increase it and look at how big the result gets when you do that

Comment: this is the same command the OP specified in their question