# Getting error while using aggregate in mongoDB and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting the following error while using aggregate method in mongoDB.

> Error:

```
Error: 13-05-2020 10:14:33 - MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object]
    at new MongooseError (/home/anil/Desktop/new/EdQart_Project/local/edqart-store-setup-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/mongooseError.js:10:11)
    at Function.Model.$handleCallbackError (/home/anil/Desktop/new/EdQart_Project/local/edqart-store-setup-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4604:11)
```

I am using mongoose with Node.js to retrieve the data from collection. I am explaining the query below.

```
const orders = await collection.aggregate(
                [
                {$match:filters}, 
                {$sort:sort}
                ], 
                {allowDiskUse: true}
                );
```

Here to avoid the `sort limit` issue I have used `{allowDiskUse: true}` and while fetching data I am getting that error. I need to resolve that issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB allowDiskUse not working..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491245/mongodb-allowdiskuse-not-working)

Comment: collection.aggregate takes the second argument as callback function, i.e
collection.aggregate( [] , callback() )
and not collection.aggregate( [] , {allowDiskUse: true} )