# Exceeded Memory Limit despite allowDiskUse set to true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I get the same error `StitchServiceError {message: "(Location16945) Exceeded memory limit for $group, … external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.", name: "StitchServiceError", errorCode: 11, errorCodeName: "MongoDBError"` whether or not I pass `{allowDiskUse:true}`.

I am passing the option as follows:

```
    db.col.aggregate(
              [
{
            $match: {
              ...
            }
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: "$...",
              items: {
                $push: {
                  ...
                }
              }
            }
          }
       ],
              {allowDiskUse:true}
            ).toArray().then(items => { console.log(items); this.setState({ forecast: items }) })
```

As suggested here: [MongoDB allowDiskUse not working..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491245/mongodb-allowdiskuse-not-working)

I am using `mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk`

Comment: Strange when you get an error "*Exceeded memory limit for $group*" but you don't use any `$group` in your aggregation pipeline.

Comment: The linked error seems to be an old bug in MongoDB

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I deleted my actual pipeline for brevity but yes I will put back a simplified version as that is confusing